# How to swap rows / columns of a Datatable in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatables

I refer to [that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721829/how-do-i-create-a-highchart-from-datatables), which is very similar to my need, as my datatable is very similar to the one used.
My question does not refer to the Datatable but to the Hightcart: I need, using a line type rather than column type, to have the years on the xAxis rather than the categories, and the categories as series.

Would you know how I could amend the code?

```
`$(document).ready(function() {

  var allSeriesData = [];
  var categories = [];

  var table = $("#example1").DataTable({
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
      let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

      // get the x-axis caregories from the table headings:
      var headers = api.columns().header().toArray();
      headers.forEach(function(heading, index) {
        if (index > 0 && index < headers.length - 1) {
          categories.push($(heading).html());
        }
      });

      // get the seris data as an array of numbers from the table row data:
      let rows = api.rows().data().toArray();
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        group = {
          name: '',
          data: []
        };
        row.forEach(function(cell, idx) {
          if (idx == 0) {
            group.name = cell;
          } else if (idx < row.length - 1) {
            group.data.push(parseFloat(cell.replace(/,/g, '')));
          }
        });
        allSeriesData.push(group);
      });  
    }
  });

  var myChart = Highcharts.chart("container", {
    chart: {
      type: "line"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Test Data"
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: categories
    },
    series: allSeriesData
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Highcharts `Data module` as follows:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<table id="datatable"> ... </table>
```

**JS**

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  data: {
    table: datatable,
    complete: function(options) {
      options.series.forEach(series => {
        series.data = series.data.map(function(data) {
          if (typeof data[1] === 'string') {
            return [data[0], parseInt(data[1].replace(/,/g, ''))];
          } else {
            return [data[0], data[1]];
          }
        });
      })
    }
  },
  chart: {
    type: "line"
  },
  title: {
    text: "Test Data"
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7egbdvfh/

API References:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

Comment: Thank you Magdalena. It works fine for a "simple" datatable created directly in html. But when Building the Datatables [the usual way](https://datatables.net/examples/api/highcharts) , the highchart is empty. I think what is missing are these parts: `table.on('draw', function () {` and `function chartData(table) {` Would you know how I can add that part?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your question because you referred to Highcharts itself, not datatables.net. In that case, I hope someone familiar with that library will provide the right answer.